# Unable to clone drive, keeps crashing, how to recover?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, disk-utility

I would like to get data off from one external drive to another. Unfortunately some files must be corrupted or has issues. Whenever I try to copy everything (15TB) the whole macOS Sierra OS just freezes and die.

I've tried copying using disk utility, command lines and other tools such as CCC and superduper. All the same thing.

I came across this thread [How to identify and fix files with corrupted / inaccessible disk blocks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129030/how-to-identify-and-fix-files-with-corrupted-inaccessible-disk-blocks)

And I was able to identify one bad file (for now). But it doesn't explain how I can bypass that and just copy over **only the good files**.

What should I do to copy just the good files to the other drive?

Comment: Ummm 1 drive, 15TB? Is it a raid or did you mean GB?

Comment: Is it built with MacOS's software raid tool? Can you repair the raid in any way? Is there a backup or parity (ie. Actual backup copy or raid: 1,5,6,10) or is it RAID 0?

Comment: It is a promise raid drive, raid 5. How do I repair the raid?

Comment: Watch this tutorial. It's for the R6, but most of the steps will apply to any Promise RAID product

Comment: What tutorial? ...

Comment: I thought I included the link. Huh... here it is: https://vimeo.com/71543188